# Regex to ignore paths starting with word or files starting with underscore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rails-admin

I have been working on a Ruby on Rails project which has greedy asset precompile regex (which is desirable in my case, because I'm not including ):

```
# in config/application.rb
# this excludes all files which start with an '_' character (sass)
config.assets.precompile << /(?<!rails_admin)(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])([^\/])*.s?css$/
```

In this same project, I am using the [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) plugin. I need my greedy regex to ignore `rails_admin` assets. I started to play around with some [regex on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/4oStq1phP6) but couldn't get the last three examples (*anything* that starts with **`rails_admin`**) to be discarded.

How can I use regex that ignores **all** rails_admin assets and those whose file names begin with an `_`, but still grabs everything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%r{               # Use %r{} instead of /…/ so we don't have to escape slashes
  \A              # Make sure we start at the front of the string
  (?!rails_admin) # NOW ensure we can't see rails_admin from here 
  ([^_/]|/[^_])   # (I have no idea what your logic is here)
  ([^/]*)         # the file name
  \.s?css         # the extension
  \z              # Finish with the very end of the string
}x                # Extended mode allows us to put spaces and comments in here
```

Note that in Ruby regex `^` and `$` match the start/end of a *line*, not the string, so it's generally better to use `\A` and `\z` instead.

---

**Edit**: Here's a modified version that allows any paths:

```
%r{               # Use %r{} instead of /…/ so we don't have to escape slashes
  \A              # Make sure we start at the front of the string
  (?!rails_admin) # NOW ensure we can't see rails_admin from here 
  (.+/)?          # Anything up to and including a slash, optionally
  ([^/]*)         # the file name
  \.s?css         # the extension
  \z              # Finish with the very end of the string
}x                # Extended mode allows us to put spaces and comments in here
```

---

Based on your edits and comments, here's a regex that matches:

- any file that ends with .css or .scss
- but not if the path starts with `rails_admin`
- and not if the filename starts with an underscore

### Demo: http://rubular.com/r/Y3Mn3c9Ioc

```
%r{               # Use %r{} instead of /…/ so we don't have to escape slashes
  \A              # Make sure we start at the front of the string
  (?!rails_admin) # NOW ensure we can't see rails_admin from here 
  (?:.+/)?        # Anything up to and including a slash, optionally (not saved)
  (?!_)           # Make sure that we can't see an underscore immediately ahead
  ([^/]*)         # the file name, captured
  \.s?css         # the extension
  \z              # Finish with the very end of the string
}x                # Extended mode allows us to put spaces and comments in here
```

Comment: Using `\A` and `\z` ignores all files in subdirectories: http://rubular.com/r/QaVd6us1qI

Comment: @parkr You have not been sufficiently clear about what directories you want to match and what you do not want to match. Please edit your question with accurate test cases. This answer is based off your statement, _"anything that starts with rails_admin to be discarded"_.

Comment: See the line in my answer where I wrote "I have no idea what your logic is here"? That's your problem: you are preventing slashes from occurring. Further, you are using a single string input in Rubular to test many different strings, so of course using `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$` won't work.

Comment: `([^_/]|/[^_])` ensures that no files starting with `_` are included. Where should I insert that regex?

Comment: @parkr See my edit. In the future, please lay out clear examples of what you do want matched and do not want matched from the start.

Comment: I thought the Rubular example would be enough. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @parkr The Rubular test cases were nice, but 1) they aren't here in Stack Overflow (what if Rubular is down?), and moreover 2) they did not tell me which lines should be matched, which lines shouldn't be matched and which parts of the string (if any) you wanted saved in captures.

Comment: It's perfect. I needed to do some testing, and it's passed all my tests. Thanks!